# How does the slack variable work in the problem formulation?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Recently I am reading a [paper](https://www1.se.cuhk.edu.hk/%7Emanchoso/papers/outage_txbeam-TSP.pdf). In it, after they achieve eq(15), which is

$$ \operatorname{Tr}(\boldsymbol{Q})-\sqrt{2 \ln (1 / \rho)} \sqrt{\|\boldsymbol{Q}\|_F^2+2\|\boldsymbol{r}\|^2}+\ln (\rho) \cdot \lambda^{+}(\boldsymbol{Q})+s \geq 0 $$

Then they said "By introducing suitable slack variables, one can easily show that the above constraint is equivalent to the following system of LMI and SOC constraints:
$$\begin{aligned}
& \operatorname{Tr}(\boldsymbol{Q})-\sqrt{2 \ln (1 / \rho)} \cdot x+\ln (\rho) \cdot y+s \geq 0, \\
& \sqrt{\|\boldsymbol{Q}\|_F^2+2\|\boldsymbol{r}\|^2} \leq x, \\
& y \boldsymbol{I}_n+\boldsymbol{Q} \succeq \mathbf{0},
\end{aligned}$$

where $\lambda^+(\mathbf{Q}) = max( \lambda_{max}(\mathbf{-Q}) , 0 )$ and $\lambda_{max}$ means take largest eigenvalue.

I didn't quite get how this slack works, could anyone help me a little about it? The first slack actually I basically get it, but the second one I didn't really see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring for a moment that you are dealing with an inequality, then you are trying to introduce a variable $y$ that equals $\lambda^+(Q)$, the negative of the most negative eigenvalue of $Q$. The way you do this is to ask what value does $y$ have to have so that if you shift the spectrum of $Q$ by $y$, you end up with something that is positive semidefinite -- in other words, you need a $y$ so that
$$
  Q+ yI \succeq 0.
$$
Any $y$ that satisfies this inequality will then also satisfy
$$
  y \ge \lambda_\text{max}(-Q).
$$
Now you just have to think a bit about the fact that $\lambda^+$ isn't just the eigenvalue (but a non-negative version of it).

Comment: Sir, I got a little further question here. So this "slack" procedure is more about to achieve a convex formulation or whether it makes this constraint easier to be satisfied? As for the first slack, we actually now subtracting a larger $x$ here to let the LHS larger than 0, it looks like we are demanding more here but not "slack". Maybe I misunderstand the meaning of "slack" here?

Comment: Here, the introduction of a slack variable is because you want to make the objective function linear in $y$ rather than having the awkward, nonlinear and nonsmooth $\lambda^+$ term. Of course, in general you pay for this by introducing a nonlinear and nonsmooth constraint. However, in this particular case, you get a constraint that requires a matrix to be semidefinite, and there are good techniques ("semidefinite programming", SDP) for this specific kind of constraint.

Comment: Got it! Really thanks for the explanation. Now I got it the slack here is for the linear function here. Sorry for replying late.